# How do you despine a facetgrid in Seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, seaborn, visualization

I have created the following plot in Seaborn using:

```
ax = sns.factorplot(x='metric', y='number', hue='drop', data=df, kind='bar')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.925)
ax._legend.remove()
sns.despine(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, this throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'spines'
```

I need to either turn the spines white or remove them, how can you do this for a factorplot/FacetGrid?

Comment: `factorplot` returns a FacetGrid, not an Axes object, so I would call that `fg` instead of `ax`. Then I would do `despine(fig=fg.fig)`

Comment: Hi @PaulH, this did not work unfortunately, I did exactly as you suggested but I had to write sns.despine(fig=fg.fig). It did not remove the axes but it didn't error. Am I missing something?

Comment: which spines do you want removed? by default only the left and top are removed

Comment: I would like the left and bottom removed (the left is not currently being removed)

Comment: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.despine.html#seaborn.despine

Comment: Thank you, I have now changed to left=True and bottom=True and it works perfectly

Comment: This should be written as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the following line

```py
sns.despine(ax=ax)
```

with

```py
ax.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

**Note:** The name `ax` is misleading, `grid` would be more indicative of what it is (a `FacetGrid` object).